# node js nested Q.all await resolve

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, q

```
//pseudo code
function f2(){
    var deferred = Q.defer();
    Q.all(chunked.map(f12)).then(function(results){
        Q.all(results.map(f13)).then(function(){
            //f13 returns promise that return value
            deferred.resolve();
        });
    });
    return deferred.promise;
}

f2().then(function(){
    console.log("end");
});
```

So I have deffered function and I know about "anti-pattern" but I have specific function that need to be deffered. And I have two nested q.all functions. All is working good but f2().then(... does not wait for deferred.resolve() and immediately throws "end" in console and after that executes all "queued" promises. So what I can do to await the resolve ?

Comment: With `deferred.resolve();` you resolve the promise that is returned by the `f2`  function.

Comment: yes. I need to resolve f2() after all nested promises in it will be resolved.

Comment: Can you provide running example and explain slightly better what you are trying to do?

Comment: Right now you resolve the promise multible times. I thing you want something like  `return Q.all(chunked.map(f12)).then(function(results){ //...`

Comment: Also I don't know so much about Q (except for stackOverflow tag definition), has it any difference from regular Promise object relevant to this question or your function is expected to do the same (except for that exceptions being "piped" to rejection)?. **EDIT:** Sorry. I didn't noticed `.defer()` call belongs to Q.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others said, (and after reading a few about `Q.defer()`) I see you are resolving `deferred` variable multiple times.

If I understood what you are trying to do right, you should resolve after (actually "on") outer `Q.all()` promise resolution.

```
//pseudo code
function f2(){
    var deferred = Q.defer();
    Q.all(chunked.map(f12)).then(function(results){
        // Notice prepended 'return' to not break the chain.
        return Q.all(results.map(f13)).then(function(){
            //f13 returns promise that return value
            //deferred.resolve(); // Wrong.
            return f13;
        });
    }).then(function(arr){

        deferred.resolve(arr); // <-- This resolves ONCE.

        // Of course you don't need to return arr if you doesn't
        // care about it. But I think is always better to do things right.
        return arr; // Also unnecessary unless you could want to chain
                    // another .then() to the outer promise.
    });
    return deferred.promise;
}

f2().then(function(){
    console.log("end");
});
```

Hope it helps (of course, untested: It may contain errors, but I think it explains the concept).

**EDIT:** I missed to say (even you told you know it is an antipattern), that, *at least in your example* there is no reason to use `Q.defer()` because you can directly return outer Q.all() promise...

Maybe what you post is only a simplified version of more complex code...

But below should expose equivalent behaviour and is much more simple:

```
//pseudo code
function f2(){
    return Q.all(chunked.map(f12)).then(function(results){
        // Notice prepended 'return' to not break the chain.
        return Q.all(results.map(f13)).then(function(){
            return f13;
        });
    })
}

f2().then(function(){
    console.log("end");
});
```

Comment: "*at least in your example*" - there's *always* no reason to use `Q.defer` when you already have promises

Comment: Of course @Bergi!! ...I would mean there is no reason "to not remove deferred usage" in that simple snippet. More coplex code could be harder to refactor (even I also think it would be very good idea to do so).

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant, one should always refactor the deferred antipattern, no matter how complex the code is, not just in this example.

Comment: True, but to refactor you previously need working code or at least, code you know exactly what it does (even if it is wrong). Otherwise you could end up doing what a collegue of me calls "refucktoring" (instead of refactoring) which consists trying to alter your program behaviour AT THE SAME TIME you are changing implementation approach ;-).

Comment: Avoiding the deferred antipattern might alter the program behaviour, but usually to the good: it implicitly fixes the often broken "edge" case of rejections, without you even noticing.

Comment: I know. But I think you didn't understood me too. I didn't say that it shouldn't be fixed: Just that is not a good idea to "make all changes at once". Wrong code is also useful: It serves to better understand our mistakes and writte better code in the future. This is why this question seemed interesting to me: The user already knew that it is an antipattern but anyway wanted to know why. ;-)